# Manipulating Excel with powershell

Tags: excel, powershell, cmd, automation

Good day everybody, so we are trying to automate some Excel and have encountered a few errors, so we have the script that is listed below, but we ran into 3 different errors.

Could someone help us identify where the script went wrong?

The error that we are getting are:

```
Exception calling  "Open" with  "1" arguments : "Server error. (excpetion  HRESULT: 0x80010105 (RPC_E_SERVERFAU
LT))"
C:\Users\Montage\Desktop\blockadp.ps1:9 char:34
+ $workbook = $excel.workbooks.open <<<< ($excelMacrosFile);
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ComMethodTargetInvocation

Cant call a method with  NULL.
C:\Users\Montage\Desktop\blockadp.ps1:10 char:39
+ $worksheet = $workbook.worksheets.item <<<< (1);
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (item:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Exception calling "Run" with "31" arguments: "server error. (excpetion from HRESULT: 0x80010105 (RPC_E_SERVERFAU
LT))"
C:\Users\Montage\Desktop\blockadp.ps1:11 char:11
+ $excel.Run <<<< ("Convert", $inputExcelFile, $outputADSFile);
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

cannot call a method with NULL.
C:\Users\Montage\Desktop\blockadp.ps1:13 char:16
+ $workbook.close <<<< ();
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (close:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

The script itself:

```
$excelMacrosFile = "C:\Users\Montage\Desktop\friday.xls";
$inputExcelFile = "C:\Users\Montage\Desktop\25.05.17.xls";
$outputADSFile = "C:\Users\Montage\Desktop\25.05.17.adp";

$excel = new-object -comobject excel.application;

$workbook = $excel.workbooks.open($excelMacrosFile);
$worksheet = $workbook.worksheets.item(1);
$excel.Run("Convert", $inputExcelFile, $outputADSFile);
#$workbook.save();
$workbook.close();
$excel.quit();
```

Even if I try this only "https://support.jamsscheduler.com/hc/en-us/articles/206191918-How-to-Automate-the-opening-of-an-Excel-Spreadsheet-in-Powershell"

```
$excelMacrosFile = "C:\Users\Montage\Desktop\friday.xls";
$excel = new-object -comobject excel.application;
$workbook = $excel.workbooks.open($excelMacrosFile);
```

Then I still get the same error

```
Exception calling "Open" with "1" argument(s): "The server threw an exception. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010105
(RPC_E_SERVERFAULT))"
```

It's also not permissions as mentioned below since this works:

```
$test = Get-Content 'C:\Users\Montage\Desktop\25.05.17.xls
```

Comment: It's hard to decipher the cyrillic characters. Perhaps you could translate them to us? Looks like one of them mentions that something contains a NULL

Comment: Sorry, i considered not to be that relevant since the detailed description was in English,  but I have translated them anyway

Comment: Searching for the first error gives this [Q&A on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33807857/powershell-xls-to-csv-conversion-issue) indicating a permission problem. THe other errors are follow-up's

Comment: I have encountered that thread as well, the thing is, in there the issue was solved by "Script is working fine on a local file with full permissions."

But im already running from a local machine (as you can see in specified path in the script), as well as the cmd is running with administrator privilages

Comment: Can you for example do a $test = Get-Content 'C:\Users\Montage\Desktop\25.05.17.xls' ?
It would cement the fact that it's not permissions - at least at file level - that is the problem

Comment: "PS C:\Users\Montage\Desktop> $test = Get-Content 'C:\Users\Montage\Desktop\25.05.17.xls'

PS C:\Users\Montage\Desktop>"

I guess since there isn't an error, then that means that its not permissions?

Write-Host $test, outputs it without errors aswell

Comment: I agree, it does not sound like a permissions problem. Next step is to verify the data in all variables until you get the error. Run it one line at the time. Then you will be closer to the answer

Comment: This is the first line that fails: $workbook = $excel.workbooks.open($excelMacrosFile);

Others are fine.  I have edited my original post to include above mentioned information

Comment: Did you try to disable automatic calculation via ```$excel.Calculation = -4135``` before opening your workbook?

Comment: @PeterSchneider  "Exception setting "Calculation" : Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC"   "PropertyAssignmentException"

Comment: I have also updated powershell to version 5.0 just in case....  The error persists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the version of Microsoft Office that was installed was x86.
When the system itself is x64.

Testing this on x64 office showed no errors, and the script worked as intended.